# No substitution when array out of bound

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, charts

i Have a array which is of variable size.
Suppose currently the array **$type** have two elements as:

```
     Array ( [19] => create [20] => code )
```

the script i use is of like this:

```
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

      ['Task', 'Weak Area'], 
      [('<?php echo $type[0]; ?>'), 5],
      [('<?php echo $type[1]; ?>'), 4]
    ]);
```

and works fine, but since the array elements may change i tried changing the script as :

```
   function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

      ['Task', 'Weak Area'], 
      [('<?php echo $type[0]; ?>'), 5],
      [('<?php echo $type[1]; ?>'), 7],
      [('<?php echo $type[2]; ?>'), 34],
      [('<?php echo $type[3]; ?>'), 12],
      [('<?php echo $type[4]; ?>'), 40],
      [('<?php echo $type[5]; ?>'), 35]
    ]);
```

but it does not show the output if array index are out of bound.
what i wanted to do is something like if type[4] is not present it will just by pass it and show output of upto type[3], can someone please help me out.

Comment: Where do you take number from? Simple way is to iterate over `$type`.

Comment: Where do you get these values (5,7,34,12,40,35) from?

Answer (score 1):

Iteration over $type.

**Try:**

```
 function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

      ['Task', 'Weak Area'], 
      <?php foreach( $type as $val ) { ?>
      [('<?php echo  $val; ?>'), 5], // Where do you get value 5? Replace it with your source variable.
      <?php } ?>
    ]);
```